# Is Thread.Yield a standard way to determine if you have a bug in your multi threaded application C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I began reading through the information posted at http://www.albahari.com/threading/

The author stated that:

> `Sleep(0)` or Yield is occasionally useful in production code for advanced performance tweaks. It’s also an excellent diagnostic tool for helping to uncover thread safety issues: **if inserting `Thread.Yield()` anywhere in your code makes or breaks the program, you almost certainly have a bug.**

According to the [`MSDN on Thread.Yield()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.yield(v=vs.110).aspx), `Thread.Yield()` is defined as follows:

> Causes the calling thread to yield execution to another thread that is ready to run on the current processor. The operating system selects the thread to yield to.

To me, this describes the half of software development that says that race conditions can't be solved.

Is this a standard debugging practice in threading?

Comment: I've never heard of that...

Comment: I have never heard of it either. I am not new to threading but I am no master.

Comment: This is a nice idea. A problem is that you need to know or guess where to insert this call.

Comment: Looks like someone's promoting [shotgun debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging)...

Comment: The power of Thread.Yield() is that it changes *timing*.  Threading race bugs are hard to diagnose because they so are so dependent on timing.  Those bugs hide because in practice program execution is too predictable.  Until it is not, happens only once a week.  Just not often enough to ever diagnose the bug.  The kind of tools that tests an app for threading bugs intentionally injects random delays into threads to maximize the odds of triggering the failure mode.  Clearly an approach that is a heckofalot more effective then doing this yourself with Thread.Yield().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thread.Yield will help you find *some* bugs**

You actually answer you're own question here :

> Sleep(0) or Yield is occasionally useful in production code for advanced performance tweaks. It’s also an excellent diagnostic tool for helping to uncover thread safety issues: **if inserting Thread.Yield() anywhere in your code makes or breaks the program, you almost certainly have a bug.**

The key here is that the thread forfeits the right to the processor to a different thread.

Don't think it is a standard but it is definitely useful, as mentioned in the quote you included, that being said....

**Multithreaded Debugging is Hard and there is no real standard way to do it**

It is really hard to debug a multithreaded code, there are a few reasons why

1. Tools used to observe the program modify the way it is executing, which means you aren't really debugging what would be executed in production.
2. Adding methods that let you observe the state of the application temporarily needs to be synchronized as well (i.e. `Console.WriteLine` , which means different code than what is in the wild )
3. Results can vary wildly depending on the environment you are executing on, **example** your **dev box** with an **i5 and 8 gigs of RAM** might work fine but when you upload your program to the **production environment** with **16 cores and 128 gigs of RAM** you will most likely get different results

**Just throw everything against the wall and see what sticks**

This isn't a nice answer but to be honest is the way I end up debugging a lot of time, you can try techniques like :

***Compile as Release code, optimizations could change execution order of code and result in instructions for Debug build being different than Release build***

1. Running multithreaded code many times (depending on intensity between 1,000 and 1,000,000 times )
2. Calling only a few times
3. Call only one time ( might seem stupid but this has messed with me a few times)
4. Call multiple times over a long period of time ( every hour make a call for a day)

This isn't fool proof but think this is a good way to ensure you capture as many issues as you can before releasing something into the wild.

Answer (score 2):

It's good advice, but I usually use Sleep(1) instead.

One of the things that makes concurrency bugs so hard to fix is that they are hard to reproduce -- most problems manifest when you are unlucky and the OS suspends your thread at the worst possible time.

When debugging problems like this, you'll often need to test a hypothesis like "maybe it happens when my thread gets suspended here, and...".  At that point you can insert a yield or sleep, which will suspend your thread and greatly increase the likelihood of reproducing the error.

Comment: Sleep(1) means that your thread will always stop executing and forfeit the rest of it's processing time alotted by the OS. Yield only switches execution if another Thread on the same core is currently waiting to be scheduled and otherwise will continue executing your thread. So I'd say that if you really want to make your Thread halt execution there to reproduce a situation Sleep is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Thread.Sleep()` or `Thread.Yield()` won't solve your bugs, but they might hide them in some cases.  While this seems like a good thing - stopping bugs from popping up is better than having them kill your program - the reality is that you're not resolving the underlying issue.

Yes, stomping bugs in a multi-threaded program can be damned hard.  This is where you really have to understand how your threads are interacting and what happens when you have threads running simultaneously on different CPU cores, etc.  Without that understanding you'll likely never find the error in your program logic that is causing the problem in the first place.

When writing a multi-threaded program you have to make sure that every operation on shared data is atomic.  Even a simple increment operation becomes a problem when you are doing it on a shared value, which is why we have the [`Interlocked.Increment()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) method.  For everything else there are locks and so on to help you manage your thread interactions.

Examine every interaction that your threads have with shared data and make sure that there is a lock in place on the data while you are using it.  For instance, let's say you're queuing jobs for a set of worker threads to do:

```
public class WorkerThread
{
    public static readonly Queue<Job> jobs = new Queue<Job>();

    public void ThreadFunc()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (jobs.Count > 0)
            {
                Job myJob = jobs.Dequeue()
                // do something with the job...
            }
            else
                Thread.Yield();
        }
    }
}
```

Seems simple enough, and it's only going to be a few cycles between when you check for a job and then go to fetch it.  In the meantime another thread has swooped in and grabbed the waiting job out from under you.  You can solve this in a few ways, but the simplest is probably to use a thread-safe version of the queue from `System.Collections.Concurrent`:

```
public class WorkerThread
{
    public static readonly ConcurrentQueue<Job> jobs = new ConcurrentQueue<Job>();

    public void ThreadFunc()
    {
        Job myJob;
        while (true)
        {
            if (jobs.TryDequeue(out myJob))
            {
                // do something with the job...
            }
            else
                Thread.Yield();
        }
    }
}
```

In cases where you don't have a thread-safe version you'll have to fall back on either locking or some other mechanism to secure your access to the shared data.  A lock-based solution to the above might look something like this:

```
public class WorkerThread
{
    private static object _jobs_lock = new object();
    private static readonly Queue<Job> _jobs = new Queue<Job>();

    public void ThreadFunc()
    {
        Job myJob;
        while (true)
        {
            if ((myJob = NextJob()) != null)
            {
                // do something with the job...
            }
            else
                Thread.Yield();
        }
    }

    public void AddJob(Job newJob)
    {
        lock(_jobs_lock)
            _jobs.Enqueue(newJob);
    }

    private Job NextJob()
    {
        lock (_jobs_lock)
        {
            if (_jobs.Count > 0)
                return _jobs.Dequeue();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Either of those two will ensure that the collection isn't modified between testing if there is a job and actually retrieving the job from the queue.  Make sure you release the locks as fast as you can though, because otherwise you're going to have lock contention issues which can be a whole lot tougher to resolve.  Never leave a lock in place longer than absolutely necessary to do the work - in this case, test for and retrieve an item from the queue.  Do this for all of your shared resources and you won't have any more race conditions on them.

Of course there are plenty of other threading issues, including methods that are inherently thread unsafe.  Make your threads as self-dependent as you can and lock access to shared resources and you should be able to avoid most of the nasty [heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).